# How do you make RPROMPT in zsh update itself on every enter?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, zsh, prompt

My `RPROMPT` is set to display svn info using `vcs_info`. It reads `RPROMPT=${vcs_info_msg_0_}`. `vcs_info` is called using `precmd()`. However, RPROMPT doesn't update when I change directories. It works only if I invoke the prompt again (either by source ~/.zshrc or prompt ) and doesn't change upon chdir, unless I invoke the prompt again. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try putting single quotes around the variable value at assignment to delay evaluation:

```
RPROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}'
```

Comment: why does the check mark go away when it gets migrated?

Comment: @user5383: You should ask that on meta.unix.stackexchange.com or meta.stackoverflow.com. I don't know (or only vaguely know) the answer.

Comment: This requires that `setopt PROMPT_SUBST` has occurred earlier in the file. Otherwise, it will just echo the prompt out literally.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single-quote to delay evaluation works for defining dynamic aliases as well.  Here's an alias, `t`, used to attach a new shell to an existing ssh agent process, which was started with an alias called `ssh-start` that writes out shell code to a file in a homedir:

```
mymistress:~> which ssh-start
ssh-start: aliased to eval `ssh-agent | tee ~/.ssh/ssh-agent.out` ; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
mymistress:~> grep "alias t" .zshrc    
alias t="eval `cat ~/.ssh/ssh-agent.out`"
mymistress:~> which t
t: aliased to eval SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-nZBZp29804/agent.29804; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;\nSSH_AGENT_PID=29805; export SSH_AGENT_PID;\necho Agent pid 29805;`
```

That definition of `t` is bad because it causes new information from a fresh run of `ssh-start` to be ignored. Changing the alias definition of `t` to be singly quoted in my .zshrc gives much better behavior:

```
mymistress:~> grep "alias t" .zshrc
alias t='eval `cat ~/.ssh/ssh-agent.out`'
mymistress:~> source ~/.zshrc
mymistress:~> which t
t: aliased to eval `cat ~/.ssh/ssh-agent.out`
```

Note the expansion of the definition of `t` as provided by `which t`, showing the effects of double quotes (immediate in-place expansion of commands or environment variables) vs. single quotes (delayed evaluation of commands and variables).